# Warning: mCrypt extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work

Tags: php, opencart, mcrypt

I'm trying to install OpenCart but get the following warning:
"Warning: mCrypt extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work!"

Since I'm a noob on this, could someone point me in the right direction on how to solve this? Google don't really help me out here :(

Thanks!

Comment: You can find your answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/564104

Comment: I found that aswell but unfortunately but i can't figure out where to write the three lines of code that suppose to fix the issue? Sorry... :(

Comment: contact your server administrator and ask them to install mcrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by put in COMMENT the error message validation for mCrypt inside the file

```
/install/controller/install/step_2.php change inside private function validate()  
//if (!function_exists('mcrypt_encrypt')) {
//  $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_mcrypt');
//}
```

and voila

and after install this extension
Then, you may want to try this extension:

(https://www.opencart.com/index.php?rout ... n_id=35487)

Answer (score 1):

So you said you have FTP access and you can edit php.ini.

If the server has mcrypt installed but not enabled then if you add:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

then save php.ini and upload, this should work.
Note that some servers don't load user's php.ini, instead they are looking for a .user.ini file in root folder.

I would suggest you, if my above answer doesn't help you to contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a linux system and you have access to the console, you can just activate the `mcrypt` module in the `php.ini`.

1. Type into your console:

   ```
   $ sudo php5enmod mcrypt
   ```

   This will enable the module. If you are using PHP 7 instead of PHP 5 use `phpenmod` instead.
2. If you get an error, install the module first with

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
   ```

   or for PHP 7 with

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt
   ```
3. After this you have to restart your webserver. Use this command for apache2

   ```
   $ sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

   or this command for nginx

   ```
   $ sudo service nginx restart
   ```

---

If you dont have access to your terminal by any reason, it could be possible to enable it trough the control panel (cPanel, Plesk, ...). In the most cases it's a one-click activation and not really complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have access to the php.ini file on the FTP is this where I should write this? So sorry but I don't know what a console really is? But I do have access to a controlpanel from my web-hotel provider.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using ***apache2*** on ***ubuntu*** :

First try to enable mcrypt using command:

```
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```

If mcrypt is not installed, install it using below commands for PHP

PHP 5.6 :

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mcrypt
```

PHP 7.0:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mcrypt
```

Enable mcrypt after insatallation and restart apache

```
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that always works with me it to use PHP 5 & mySQL 5 (5.x anything)
And in the hosting, assign the php version 5 (outdated) to the website, also make sure that the database is mySQL (5.x)

Thanks